# Help bogged down at first query

Tags: front-end, bugs

When I open help at the first time in a mathematica session and I submit a query it always get bogged down for many seconds until a message appears as in the picture. Then I select continue waiting, I press the search button again and the results immediately appear and there are no problems in the following searches. It's not a very big problem but somewhat annoying. Can someone help me?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just to confirm the same behavior on V9.01 Win 7. Very annoying. Has already been discussed in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=8025283#8025283) several times. Does not happen if the input for the help system is a properly spelled symbol (`sin` vs. `Sin`). I would recommend submitting a bug report in any case.

Comment: I have seen this same behavior on a similar system too. I presume it's looking on the Wolfram servers for a match.

Comment: I experienced this earlier today on V9.0.1 Win 8, but it's working fine now.

Comment: This is likely the same problem and solution as [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18960/documentation-searches-hang-frequently-anyone-else-dealing-with-this).